# Remove last argument from argument list of shell script (bash)

Tags: bash, shell, argument-passing, automator

This question concerns a bash script that is run in automator osx. I am using automator actions to get and filter a bunch of file references from the finder. Then I append to that list the name of the parent folder, also via an automator action. Automator then feeds these arguments to an action called "run shell script". I am not sure exactly how automator invokes the script but the argument list looks like this when echoed with: `echo "$@"`

> /Volumes/G-Raid/Online/WAV_TEST/Testbok 50/01/01000 43-001.wav /Volumes/G-Raid/Online/WAV_TEST/Testbok 50/02/02000 43-002.wav /Volumes/G-Raid/Online/WAV_TEST/Testbok 50/03/03000 43-003.wav /Volumes/G-Raid/Online/WAV_TEST/Testbok 50

In this case path to 3 files and a folder.

In the shell script I launch an application called ripcheckc* with the args passed from automator minus the last argument(the folder) in the list.

I use this to remove the last argument:

```
_args=( "$@" )
unset _args[${#_args[@]}-1]
```

And this is `echo $_args`:

> /Volumes/G-Raid/Online/WAV_TEST/Testbok 50/01/01000 43-001.wav /Volumes/G-Raid/Online/WAV_TEST/Testbok 50/02/02000 43-002.wav /Volumes/G-Raid/Online/WAV_TEST/Testbok 50/03/03000 43-003.wav

Same as before but without the folder.

Now, if I run ripcheckc with `"$@"` as argument it works (but fails later on because of that last path in the argument list) If I use `${_args[@]}` the application will just abort silently. When I echo `$@` and `_args` the output looks identical except for the last argument.

My question is - what is the difference between $@ and $_args that make the first valid input and the second not?

*The application is [ripcheckc](http://sourceforge.net/projects/ripcheck/files/?source=navbar)

I hope my question makes sense.

EDIT: Solved.

Comment: I solved it by using double quotes. Like this: ripcheckc "${_args[@]}".

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Assuming that you already have an `array`, you can say:

```
unset "array[${#array[@]}-1]"
```

---

For example, if your script contains:

```
array=( "$@" )
unset "array[${#array[@]}-1]"    # Removes last element -- also see: help unset
for i in "${array[@]}"; do
  echo "$i"
done
```

invoking it with: `bash scriptname foo bar baz` produces:

```
foo
bar
```

Comment: Thank you, that is a better way to get rid of the last argument. My issue is that there seems to be something different about $@ compared to $array that qualifies it as valid input for the application I am passing it to. I just can't figure out what it is.

Comment: @user1047256 Try passing `${array[@]}` to your application.

Comment: I tried what you suggested but still no go. Fyi I changed my nick to Nordanfors. :-)

Comment: @Nordanfors How do you pass parameters to your __application__ otherwise?  (Could you update the question with the information?)

Comment: Your help is most appreciated. All that was missing was double quotes around the array to get the application to process it. Thanks!

Comment: @Nordanfors _Always_ quote variables.

Comment: The next answer should be accepted, not this one. It has triple the upvotes.

Comment: @Noumenon: **Bienvenue StackOverflow.** The accepted answer declining to abject uselessness over time is the common case, rendering this StackOverflow feature an anti-pattern in UX design. The evolving democratic wisdom of the crowds `>>>>` the non-democratic and rapidly obsoleted decision of a single individual.

Comment: There's an advantage to this approach: The "pop" operation becomes O(1), so you can put it in a loop. Allocating the array is still O(n) and slower than using the subarray approach, but this has its merits.

Answer (score 59):

I have used this `bash` one-liner before

```
set -- "${@:1:$(($#-1))}"
```

It sets the argument list to the current argument list, less the last argument.

---

How it works:

- `$#` is the number of arguments
- `$((...))` is an arithmetic expression, so `$(($#-1))` is one less than the number of arguments.
- `${variable:position:count}` is a [substring expression](http://www.tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/string-manipulation.html): it extracts `count` characters from `variable` starting at position. In the [special case](http://www.tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/string-manipulation.html) where `variable` is `@`, which means the argument list, it extracts `count` **arguments** from the list beginning at `position`. Here, `position` is `1` for the first argument and `count` is one less than the number of arguments worked out previously.
- `set -- arg1...argn` [sets the argument list](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/The-Set-Builtin.html) to the given arguments

So the end result is that the argument list is replaced with a new list, where the new list is the original list except for the last argument.

Comment: Simple and elegant: I like it.  I used a variation of @chepner's suggestion below to "remove" the first two arguments in order to properly spawn a sub-process: spawnProc "${@:3:$#}".  Admittedly cryptic but that's due to BASH's roots.  It's elegant though and simple.

Comment: Could I request a play-by-play of this thing?

Comment: @StevenLu I have amended the answer to provide an explanation for you. I hope it helps.

Comment: That’s perfect!

Comment: Great explanation, note there's an even more compact way of writing by @uvsmtid below, which is `"${@:1:${#}-1}"`

Comment: The "special case" applies to any array variable, not just `@`.

Answer (score 11):

You can also get all but the last argument with

```
"${@:0:$#}"
```

which, honestly, is a little sketchy, since it seems to be (ab)using the fact that arguments are numbered starting with 1, not 0.

Update: This only works due to a bug (fixed in 4.1.2 at the latest) in handling `$@`. It works in version 3.2.

Comment: Code `"${@:1:${#}-1}"` is exactly what makes full list of arguments like in "$@" without the last one.

Comment: Right. The sketchy part is using 0 as the first argument to avoid having to subtract 1 from the second.

Comment: Actually, index 0 includes non-argument - path to the script being executed (a value automatically provided by shell). You are not avoiding subtraction of 1 - the last argument is still included and you must subtract 1. Using 0 is simply adding one more (likely not required) value to the list.

Comment: It would appear this worked in `bash` 3.2 due to a bug that was subsequently fixed.

Answer (score 2):

```
set -- "${@:1:$#-1}"
```

sets the parameter list to first up to penultimate, removing the last one