# cant create third parameter in bash script (after $*)

Tags: linux, bash, parameters

I want to create a bash script, that gets 3 parameters. But the second needs to be `$*`, because i need later these lines. The other two parameters (first and third) doesn't need this.

```
for x in $* do
```

The first and second parameter aren't the problem, this one works:

```
parameter1="$1"
shift
parameter2="$*"
```

But i need the third parameter at the end and something like this

```
parameter1="$1"
parameter3="$3"
shift
parameter2="$*"
```

won't work. My command at the end should look like this:

```
bash myscript parameter1 parameter2 parameter3
```

Comment: Do you mean that you want the first and last parameters, then to loop over all the ones in the middle?

Comment: `$*`, by its nature, captures all your remaining arguments into a single string. **All of them**.

Comment: (That also means you lose the distinction between `"one arg" "another arg"` and `one arg another arg` or `"one arg another arg"` -- in general, `$*`'s effects are undesired, and you shouldn't use it as you are here).

Comment: ...which is to say: `for x in $*` is basically always wrong. `for x in "$@"` is the Right Thing.

Comment: BTW, I'm not sure that there's enough context here to explain *why* you think you need `$*` or `"$@"`. Instead of `myscript parameter1 parameter2 parameter3`, why not `myscript parameter1 "parameter2" parameter3`, and use `"$2"` for the second one?

Comment: BTW, this is closely related to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20398499/remove-last-argument-from-argument-list-of-shell-script-bash

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For specifically three parameters, you can use substring parameter expansion in a simple way:

```
parameter1=$1
parameter2="${@:2:1}"   # One parameter, starting with #2
parameter3=$3
```

Or course, that's unnecessary, since you can just use `$2` instead of `${@:2:1}`, but I point it out as a simple introduction to the syntax (and not at all because I overlooked the fact you would use `$2`, really....)

(You can also use it as a substitute for indirect parameter expansion; `"${@:n:1}"` and `"${!n}"` are basically equivalent when `n` is a variable with an integer value.)

For the more general case, where you want an arbitrary number of arguments between the first and last, it gets a little more complicated, although the principle is the same:

```
parameter1=$1
middleParameters=( "${@:2:$#-2}" )  # n - 2 parameters, starting with #2, i.e., all but $1 and ${!n} for n=$#
lastParameter="${@:$#}"
```

Comment: Are you sure about "${@:n:1}" and "${!n}" are basically equivalent?  I try : set A B C ; B=99 ; echo "${@:2:1}" ; echo "${!2}", and I get "B" on the first line, and 99 on the second line.  Did I understand it incorrectly?

Comment: I should have been more explict; I meant a *literal* variable `n` with an integer value for that equivalency. (I said "basically" because I also didn't bother checking for other differences for things like out-of-bounds indices in each case.)

Comment: Ok, I tested that, and I see that it works.  So, if I understand correctly, if the start index used in the expansion is a literal integer, it is is used as is, but if it is a variable name, it expands to the value of that variable.  Am I stating that correctly?

Comment: Right; the indices are evaluated in an arithmetic context, just as if you had written `${@:$((n)):1}` instead.

Answer (score 2):

`shift` removes an argument from the left. If you want to remove an argument from the *right*, you can do that with:

```
set -- "${@:1:$# - 1}"
```

Thus:

```
parameter1=$1          # capture leftmost argument
shift                  # remove leftmost argument

parameter3=${*:$#:1}   # capture rightmost argument
set -- "${@:1:$# - 1}" # remove rightmost argument

parameter2=$*          # concatenate remaining arguments and store in a string
```

---

Note that `$*` is almost certainly the Wrong Thing. If you want to keep your arguments separate, respecting their quoting, instead use an array:

```
parameter2=( "$@" )
for item in "${parameter2[@]}"; do
  echo "Processing item: $item"
done
```

If your script is run as `yourscript arg1 "item A" "item B" arg3`, then the above will ensure that `item A` and `item B` are treated as individual arguments, rather than treating `item` as an argument, `A` as another, etc.

Comment: Sorry, but what do you mean with 'argument from the left' or 'right'? Do you mean, that $* ignores with shift the parameter on the left side?

Comment: @ipo, I mean `shift` removes the old `$1` from the argument list altogether, and makes the thing that was `$2` be `$1`, the thing that was `$3` be `$2`, the thing that was `$4` be `$3`, etc. If before you ran `shift`, `$1` was `one` and `$2` was `two`, then *after* `shift`, then `$1` is `two`, and the `one` is *gone*.

Comment: @ipo, ...and to be clear, that's *always* what it does; it's not some kind of magic "remove whatever I just read" operation; instead, it takes things off the left-hand side of the argument list, and *shifts* whatever was to the right of those things over to fill in the vacated positions.

Comment: @ipo, ...`$*`, by contrast, takes *the entire argument list* and crams it into one string, with the first character of the IFS variable (by default, a space) injected between those arguments. If you used `shift` to take something out of the argument list, then for that reason that thing will no longer be included in `"$*"`.

Comment: @ipo, ...so, you can try this: `set -- one two three; echo $1; shift; echo $1` -- you'll see that the first `echo` emits `one`, and the second one emits `two`, because `$1` changed when `shift` was called. You can replace the `$1`s with `$*`s to see the impact there as well.